# Mimic Microsoft Access Query Wizard

Tags: jquery-ui, svg

I would like to draw a line connecting list items **Five** and **One** in this example. The line should stay attached to Five and One as the user drags the widget around.

```js
$('.ui-widget-content').draggable({ 
 handle: '.ui-widget-header' }
)
$('.ui-widget-header').disableSelection()
```

```css
.ui-widget-content { 
 width: 100px; 
 height: 100px;  
}
.ui-widget-header { 
 cursor: move; 
}
.list-unstyled {
 list-style-type:none;
 padding-left:10px;
}
.primaryKey, .secondaryKey {
 font-weight:bold
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Draggable - Handles</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget-content">
 <div class="ui-widget-header">handle One</div>
 <ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li class="primaryKey">One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="ui-widget-content">
 <div class="ui-widget-header">handle Two</div>
 <ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li>Four</li>
  <li class="secondaryKey">Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where do you want the connection points? Center of "One" and "Five"? Straight line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not too worried about the exact line path, you can do it like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image">
  <div class="ui-widget-content" id="one">
    <div class="ui-widget-header">handle One</div>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li class="primaryKey">One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="ui-widget-content" id="two">
    <div class="ui-widget-header">handle Two</div>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li>Four</li>
      <li class="secondaryKey">Five</li>
      <li>Six</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <svg class="lines" width="100%" height="500">
    <line id="linePath_1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var offset = {
    X: 0,
    Y: 0
  };

  function Point(x, y) {
    return {
      "X": x,
      "Y": y
    };
  }

  function drawLine(pointA, pointB) {
    var od = {
      a: {
        X: pointA.X - offset.X,
        Y: pointA.Y - offset.Y
      },
      b: {
        X: pointB.X - offset.X,
        Y: pointB.Y - offset.Y
      }
    };
    console.log(od);
    $("#linePath_1").attr({
      x1: od.a.X,
      y1: od.a.Y,
      x2: od.b.X,
      y2: od.b.Y
    })
  }

  $('.ui-widget-content').draggable({
    handle: '.ui-widget-header',
    containment: ".image",
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      var pkA, pkB, pointA, pointB;
      if ($(this).is("#one")) {
        pkA = $("#one .primaryKey").position();
        pkB = $("#two .secondaryKey").position();
        pointA = Point($("#one").position().left + pkA.left, $("#one").position().top + pkA.top);
        pointB = Point($("#two").position().left + pkB.left, $("#two").position().top + pkB.top);
        console.log(pointA, pointB);
      } else {
        pkA = $("#two .secondaryKey").position();
        pkB = $("#one .primaryKey").position();
        pointA = Point($("#two").position().left + pkA.left, $("#two").position().top + pkA.top);
        pointB = Point($("#one").position().left + pkB.left, $("#one").position().top + pkB.top);
        console.log(pointA, pointB);
      }
      drawLine(pointA, pointB);
    }
  });
  $('.ui-widget-header').disableSelection();
});
```

This basically puts the `<svg>` element in the background and uses the `<line>` to be drawn and updated during `drag` callback. You can base this off the `clientX` and `clientY` for the `event` if you want, but I figured you'd want it to appear to be connecting the keys.

Be mindful that `.position()` will provide the `{top, left}` of the element in the div. You could also use `.offset()`.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/chdznLnx/